# Parameter passing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following piece of code written in swift:

```
func hai(greeting: String, times: Int) -> String {
    return "You are greeted + \(greeting) + \(times) times "
}
hai ("Hello", times: 3)
```

When I call the function `hai`, if I call it the following way `hai("hello", 3)` it throws an error and forces me to call the way it was mentioned above.

Can someone please explain why this should be the case? Thanks, I am new to IOS programming.

Comment: var result:String = self.hai("Hello", times: 3)

Answer (score 3):

Each function parameter in Swift has two names - an *internal* and an *external* one. When you define function signature the way you did, the external parameter name of `times` is the same as its internal name. You can tell Swift that you do not want an external name by placing `_` in the external name position:

```
func hai(greeting: String, _ times: Int) -> String
//                         ^
```

Learn more about internal/external parameter names in the [Swift 2.2 Programming Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166).